# Можно ли выполнить данное действие Javascript циклом

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой(вопросом).
У меня достаточно простое действие при нажатии на элемент:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-plus-btn.transition_1', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(0);
  $('.add-transition.transition_1').fadeIn(250);
});
$(document).on('click', '.add-plus-btn.transition_2', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(0);
  $('.add-transition.transition_2').fadeIn(250);
});

// И так до transition_60 элементов (может быть по разному);
```

Как мне упростить код, возможно циклом for? Но никак не получается...
Спасибо!

Comment: перенести этот класс в дата атрибут и сделать один обработчик

Comment: зачем цикл, если можно повесить обработчик на `.add-plus-btn` и внутри использовать this? Правда странно как-то fadeOut и сразу fadeIn на том же элементе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, как ты будешь определять, какой из классов `transition_*` присутствует у this, если у него из несколько

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - это разные элементы

Comment: @Igor ясненько. вижу.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский элементы разные - прячем, на тот что нажимаем и показываем другой...

Comment: Зачем юзать делегирование, если всё равно куча элементов промежуточных подходит? `.add-plus-btn` тоже общий предок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var clickHandlerProvider = function(index) {
  return function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(0);
    $('.add-transition.transition_' + index).fadeIn(250);
  };
}
for (var iter = 1; iter <= 2; iter++) {
  $(document).on('click', '.add-plus-btn.transition_' + iter, clickHandlerProvider(iter));
}
```

Comment: Всё отлично работает! Спасибо!!